# How to transfer the text output into dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have done some web scraping with beautiful soup and here is the output text I got:

```
TCGA-KK-A7B3-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 5.5 Living days 899 (2.5 years)
TCGA-G9-6347-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 14.2 Living days 2089 (5.7 years)
TCGA-KC-A4BL-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 3.8 Living days 934 (2.6 years)
TCGA-KK-A7AQ-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 2.6 Living days 1610 (4.4 years)
TCGA-G9-6373-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 4.7 Living days 811 (2.2 years)
....
```

How do I save this result into a dataframe?

How to save this information into csv files.

I will need csv files to do further analysis?

Comment: Those words are separated by spaces in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA=StringIO("""
TCGA-KK-A7B3-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 5.5 Living days 899 (2.5 years)
TCGA-G9-6347-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 14.2 Living days 2089 (5.7 years)
TCGA-KC-A4BL-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 3.8 Living days 934 (2.6 years)
TCGA-KK-A7AQ-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 2.6 Living days 1610 (4.4 years)
TCGA-G9-6373-01A Male  Stage not reported  Alive FPKM 4.7 Living days 811 (2.2 years)
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=" ",header=None)
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',')
print df
```

This code will print dataframe and generate `output.csv` file.

**Update 1:**

```
list_raw=[]
for i in TESTDATA:

    list_raw.append(i.split(' '))

df=pd.DataFrame(list_raw)
print df
```

If it is in for loop reading. Use like shown above code for dataframe conversion. then do df to csv conversion as initially shown code.

Comment: Supporting both Py2 and Py3 will also require `from __future__ import print_function` under Py2 imports and `print(df)` instead of `print df`

Comment: Yes,it's correct but my output text is from a for loop. Then how to pass the result from a for loop into the 'StringIO()' ?

Comment: @RujunGuan Then use `list` to append as rows.

Comment: @RujunGuan Have you got any answer ? In case of any error just ask in comment

Comment: Just done. It has been solved now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @RujunGuan If you realize the answer is correct, You can accept this answer and eligible for an upvote. Learn here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers